# Build Error on adding FlutterToast

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to use the [FlutterToast](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluttertoast) plugin in my app. However, I am getting the following error:-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

Can anyone help? I am also using the firestore and audioplayer plugin.